# Chunk List Webpack Plugin not found

Tags: webpack

I am trying to use Chunk List Webpack Plugin from here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chunk-list-webpack-plugin

Installed as per "Getting started":

`npm install --save-dev chunk-list-webpack-plugin`

but, when I am adding it to webpack.config.js, inside "plugins" array:

`new ChunkListWebpackPlugin({output: "chunks-list.json", groupByExtension: true}),`

I get the error:

`ChunkListWebpackPlugin is not defined`.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the plugin at the top of your **webpack.config.js** file:

```
const ChunkListWebpackPlugin = require('chunk-list-webpack-plugin')
```